# Create a Custom Post from within another Custom Post

Tags: custom-post-types

Does anyone know of a way to Create a Custom Post from within another Custom Post?

Example: A custom post: Pizza can choose from a list of already made custom posts: Toppings.

If I want to add a new topping (which is a different custom post) I have to go to the Toppings custom post type and add it before it is available in the Pizza custom post. I would like to be able to add a new topping custom post from within the pizza custom post without switching screens. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Anything's possible! ;)

But this is not something WordPress will let you do out of the box, however. You'll need a plugin for this, an existing one or one you write yourself.

I guess you'd want to have a button or maybe a special choice ("New...") in your Toppings drop down menu. When selected, it could open a pop-up and load the edit screen for a custom Topping post type. You likely would want a simplified edit screen here, so it doesn't get too confusing.

You would save back the new Topping using ajax and, upon a successful save, you would add the new Topping to your current Pizza's list of toppings.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was thinking. Do you know of any plugin like this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, no. It's a pretty specialized feature, I would not be surprised this does not exist yet. You could try and write your own, or hire someone to build it for you...

Comment: Yeah, thats probably what Ill do. thought I'd ask around first. Thanks for the input